# User input for calling a method using enum (C#)

Tags: c#, enums, compiler-errors, user-input

I'm just starting to use C# and I've run into a problem. I've got a question I need to answer that needs to use enum, and needs to use a user input to trigger a switch. I've got almost all of it figured out so far, but I've got a single error that won't go away. I haven't learned enough in C# to solve this on my own yet, so I really need help. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;    

namespace enumExample
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum Operator
        {
            add,
            subtract,
            multiply,
            divide
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer");
            string leftstring = System.Console.ReadLine();
            int left = System.Convert.ToInt32(leftstring);

            System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter another integer");
            string rightstring = System.Console.ReadLine();
            int right = System.Convert.ToInt32(rightstring);

            System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter '0' to add, '1' to subtract, '2' to multiply, and '3' to divide");
            string op = System.Console.ReadLine();
            int x = System.Convert.ToInt32(op);

            double sum = Calculate(left, right, Operator.op);
            System.Console.WriteLine("The answer to your problem is {0}", sum);
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static double Calculate(int left, int right, Operator op)
        {
            double sum = 0.0;

            switch (op)
            {
                case Operator.add:
                    sum = left + right;
                    break;
                case Operator.subtract:
                    sum = left - right;
                    break;
                case Operator.multiply:
                    sum = left * right;
                    break;
                case Operator.divide:
                    sum = (double)left / right;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("An error occurred");
                    System.Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
            }

            return sum;
        }
   }
}
```

When I go to compile my program, I get this error:

```
Code: CS0117
Description: 'Program.operator' does not contain a definition for 'op'
Project: enumExample
File: Program.cs
Line: 33
Suppression State: Active
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this, and thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Your Operator enum does not have a value called "op"

On line 33 you have:

```
double sum = Calculate(left, right, Operator.op);
```

I'm guessing what you wanted to actually write is

```
double sum = Calculate(left, right, (Operator)x);
```

This will cast your int to the proper enum value.

If you want to do more of this sort of thing you may want to think about explicitly setting the values of each enum value.

```
public enum Operator
    {
        add = 0,
        subtract = 1,
        multiply = 2,
        divide = 3
    };
```

Comment: I think he wants to use the operator that has been parsed instead of a hardcoded one

Comment: I understand now.  I have edited my response to reflect the desired answer.

Comment: This won't work since op is a string, (Operator)x would work

Answer (score 0):

You've got this here:

```
double sum = Calculate(left, right, Operator.op);
```

You're saying, Operator.op. But your enum contains:

```
    public enum Operator
    {
        add,
        subtract,
        multiply,
        divide
        op <----- You don't have one of these, which you'd have to in order to pass in Operator.op.
    }
```

Perhaps you meant `double sum = Calculate(left, right, x);` (i.e. **x** there, not Operator.op.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!